# Formatted input in C

Tags: c, input, scanf

Can someone please help tell me what is wrong with my code. I am trying to ask user fro two name of his/her friends and their age. then return the average of their ages. but the output is not as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char friend1;
    char friend2;
    float age1;
    float age2;
    float average;

    printf("Please enter name of your friend...\n");
    scanf("%s", &friend1);
    printf("How old is %s?\n",&friend1);
    scanf("%f", &age1);

    printf("Enter name of one more friend!\n");
    scanf("%s",&friend2);
    printf("How old is %s?\n", &friend2);
    scanf("%f", &age2); 

    average = (age1+age2)/2;

    printf("Average age of your friends %s and %s is %4.2f years old\n"  ,&friend1,&friend2,&average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is that output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `friend1` & `friend2` as `char array` if you want to store `names` into them as below

```
char friend1[50];/** take the char array of required size **/
char friend2[50];
```

And while scanning you no need to provide `&` in `scanf`  if `friend1` is declared as `char array`, because `char array` name itself **address**.

```
printf("Please enter name of your friend...\n");
scanf("%s", friend1);
```

Apply the same for `friend2`. Also while printing don't use `&` if you want to print value of `average`.

Replace

```
 printf("Average age of your friends %s and %s is %4.2f years old\n"  ,&friend1,&friend2,&average);
```

with

```
printf("Average age of your friends %s and %s is %4.2f years old\n"  ,friend1,friend2,average);
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things -

1. In C strings are basically null terminated `char` arrays.
2. You need to have enough memory to hold the inputted characters and the `'\0'` to mark the end of the string.

You have used one `char` variable and passed it's address to `scanf`. `scanf` tries to store the input name but it will access some memory that it shouldn't resulting in  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The correct way would be to use an array with some number maximum `char` that might be there. You will do the same thing for `friend2` variable also.

```
#define MAXLETTERS 10 

char friend1[MAXLETTERS ];
if( scanf("%9s",friend1) == 1){
   // got name in friend1
}
```

Notice the `%9s` - why `9`? Because we will get `9` characters from input and the last one (10th one) will be the `\0` character. The problem with `scanf("%s",friend1)` is `%s` matches any string, of any length, and `scanf()` has no idea when to stop reading. It reads as long as it can parse the input according to the format string, as a result it writes to `friend1` more than `10` characters - leaving us with a possibility of [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).
By specifying that `9` we are telling `scanf` don't read more than `9` characters.

`&` operator when applied to variable returns the address of it - in your case after calculating the average of two friend's, you need to print it's value not it's address. So remove `&` in `printf` for the `3` variables listed in each of the cases. Just pass the value of the variables to the `printf` function not the addresses.

In case you are wondering why there is no `&` used in `scanf` with `friend1` and `friend2` - then you should know that when an array is passed to a function (here that function being `scanf`) it is converted into (known as array decaying) pointer to the first element. The first element here is `friend1[0]` and a pointer to it means that pointer's content is `&friend1[0]`. And that is what is being expected by `scanf` - the address where it will store the inputted data.

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 20k!

Comment: Agreed. It is a shame that `#define MAXLETTERS 10` can't find its way to `scanf("%9s",friend1)`. It would have been nice if the `*` field width in `printf` format specifiers could have the similar runtime use in `scanf`. But it doesn't, `*` in `scanf` is not the same.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since scanf requires a string (pointer to char), try switching to an array of char.

```
char friend1[20]; 
char friend2[20];
```

May be a valid example if the strings are less than 19 characters.